# How is a non-breaking space represented in a JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This apparently is not working:

```
X = $td.text();
if (X == '&nbsp;') {
  X = '';
}
```

Is there something about a non-breaking space or the ampersand that JavaScript doesn't like?

Comment: Not working how? What are you then doing with X?

Comment: Oh, if I say X=$td.html() it works.

Comment: Remember that `.text()` strips out markup, thus I don't believe you're going to find `&nbsp;` in a non-markup result.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but doesn't text() expand html entities?

Comment: \u00A0 - unicode nbsp
\x20 - ascii space

<p>&nbsp;P1nbsp</p>

In browser console:
/\u00A0/.test($0.childNodes[0].nodeValue[0])
Display "true"

Answer (score 390, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is a HTML entity. When doing `.text()`, all HTML entities are decoded to their character values.

Instead of comparing using the entity, compare using the actual raw character:

```
var x = td.text();
if (x == '\xa0') { // Non-breakable space is char 0xa0 (160 dec)
  x = '';
}
```

Or you can also create the character from the character code manually it in its Javascript escaped form:

```
var x = td.text();
if (x == String.fromCharCode(160)) { // Non-breakable space is char 160
  x = '';
}
```

More information about `String.fromCharCode` is available here:

> [fromCharCode - MDC Doc Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

More information about character codes for different charsets are available here:

> [Windows-1252 Charset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)
>   [UTF-8 Charset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: Ordinary spaces are breaking, so it is '\x20', but better to use ' '.

Answer (score 8):

Remember that `.text()` strips out markup, thus I don't believe you're going to find `&nbsp;` in a non-markup result.

*Made in to an answer....*

```
var p = $('<p>').html('&nbsp;');
if (p.text() == String.fromCharCode(160) && p.text() == '\xA0')
    alert('Character 160');
```

Shows an alert, as the ASCII equivalent of the markup is returned instead.

Comment: Using jQuery we can see that `$("<div>&nbsp;</div>").text().charCodeAt()` gives `160` (unicode for nbsp)

Answer (score 2):

That entity is converted to the char it represents when the browser renders the page. JS (jQuery) reads the rendered page, thus it will not encounter such a text sequence. The only way it could encounter such a thing is if you're double encoding entities.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery docs for `text()` says

> Due to variations in the HTML parsers
>   in different browsers, the text
>   returned may vary in newlines and
>   other white space.

I'd use `$td.html()` instead.

Comment: This will add html tags to your page 's markup.

For example, the string '<text>' will be an html element.