# Detect &nbsp; and space with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, whitespace, html-entities

I'm trying to read the content of a `contentEditable` div and extract the currently active word. ie. the word which was just entered or one which was modified.

My initial approach was:

1. get string as `innerHTML`
2. get cursor position using a function (now I can find the word that was modified)
3. read backwards till a space is found (character by character comparison)
4. extract the word from the point of space found.

But the problem is that the browser sometimes converts the spaces to `&amp;nbsp;` and sometimes doesn't (There is no problem if there is only one space). Then I decided to using a second loop to read in 5 chars if `a ;` is found and check against that. But this is seems very inefficient. So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just use replace (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to turn then back into spaces?

Comment: @Urbycoz: For that, again I have to pass the whole string & the replace function will parse through the whole string to replace the nbsp's. The problem is that this checking comes every time a letter is entered. So, I'm looking for the most efficient code is terms of speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a workaround. Previously, I was using innerHTML to get the contents.
Now, I'm using `targ.firstChild.nodeValue` where targ is the element whose content is needed.Then checking with  `str.charCodeAt(i)==32 || str.charCodeAt(i)==160` .

This works well.

Comment: As a better method, now I'm looking through all text nodes and thus taking the whole text.

Answer (score 16):

`String.fromCharCode(160)` worked for me. It stands for `&nbsp;` character. `if(str == ' ')` was not working in if condition, neither did trim(); but `if(str == String.fromCharCode(160))` worked.

For checking normal space use `if(str.trim() == '')`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking is here : [non-breaking space in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237989/nonbreaking-space).

Comment: Thanks, but I already seen that link .Is there any other way other than to check directly for the characters nbsp?

Comment: Well, if you need to check literals "&nbsp;", a simple regex like `/&(amp;)?nbsp;/` would suffice. But if you want to check for non-breaking spaces, since the browser transforms those into spaces, you can't differentiate them from normal spaces without checking for the character code for sure.