# Remove "&nbsp;" (none breaking space) from HTML Text using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been testing out different approached but have found no luck removing the nonbreaking spaces from text in HTML using jquery. HTML example below.

```
    <div class="row">
 <tr role="row">

   <td><span class="hide">
       20210129</span>
     01/01/2021
     &nbsp;to&nbsp;
     01/29/2021</td>
 </tr>
 </div>
```

And my JQuery:

```
test = $('.row').contents().eq(2).text().trim();
console.log(test)
```

I've tried ".replace" and seems like a no-go. I need the final result to be "01/01/2021 to 01/29/2021".

Also, my Fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/SmcMichael12/h7Lk2bp6/41/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is a non-breaking space represented in a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237989/how-is-a-non-breaking-space-represented-in-a-javascript-string) AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308797/detect-nbsp-and-space-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you want to remove line break

```
.replace(/\n/g, "")
```

```js
let test = $('.row').contents().eq(2).text().trim();
test = test.replace(/\n/g, "");
$('.test').text(test);
console.log(test)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <tr role="row">

   <td><span class="hide">
       20210129</span>
     01/01/2021
     &nbsp;to&nbsp;
     01/29/2021</td>
 </tr>
 </div>


<br><br>Result : <span class="test"></span>
```