# Matching jquery .text() to &nbsp;

Tags: jquery, text, whitespace

Due to circumstances out of my control, SharePoint, I have the following piece of code.

```
var item = $('<span><font size=1>&nbsp;</font></span>').text()
```

I am trying to compare the `.text()` value to `&nbsp;` and don't know what to do. Stepping through the code `item` seems to equal " " which makes sense. But doing `item == " "` returns false. How should this comparison be done?

EDIT: Example fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hUBeP/2/

Comment: Is it actually [character 0xA0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm)? But I think that might be browser-dependent - I wouldn't want to rely on that. Does it match a whitespace regexp?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237989/nonbreaking-space

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try checking for `'\xa0'` (which is the character created by `&nbsp;`):

```
var item = $("<span><font size=1>&nbsp;</font></span>").text();
alert("'" + item + "' " + (item == '\xa0'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hUBeP/3/

Comment: This did it! @Rup - It's only going to be running in IE so browser dependancy isn't really an issue. Cheers.

Comment: Actually it works in Firefox, too - and probably also in other browsers.

Comment: yeah I accidentally added the last comment unfinished. Now updated!

Comment: You can also use '\xa0' when adding a nonbreaking space to a span using the .text() function.

Answer (score 0):

Compare it to `&nbsp;`, as that is the content you want to match. It appears not to be that because the browser renders is as space, rather than characters. Comparing it to `&nbsp;` should result in either two sets of `&nbsp;`s being compared, or two identical spaces being compared.

Comment: Well technically I could compare it against `$("<p>&nbsp;</p>").text()`. But ThiefMaster's solution is much cleaner.

Comment: Agreed, especially since you are not concerned about cross-browser issues.