# Why does the JavaScript String whitespace character &nbsp; not match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I got in HTML the following construct:

```html
<div id="text">
  some&nbsp;text
</div>
```

If I trim the text and test it with:

```js
$("#text").text().trim() === "some text"
```

it returns `false`, also:

```js
$("#text").text().trim() === "some&nbsp;text"
```

returns `false`, but:

```js
/^some\s{1}text$/.test($("#text").text().trim())
```

returns `true`.
So please tell me, what´s wrong here.

As you would suggest, I am using jQuery (1.6).

Comment: `/^some\s{1}text$/.test("some&nbsp;text".trim())` returns `false` for me. http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/m9TXr/

Comment: as described in the answers below you need to parse it via jQuery.

Comment: Because that is not "the Javascript string whitespace character".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's because the no breaking space (charCode 160) does not exactly equal to space (charCode 32)

jquery's `.text()` encodes HTML entities to their direct unicode equivalence, and so `&nbsp;` becomes `String.fromCharCode(160)`

You can solve it by replaceing all the the non-breaking spaces with ordinary spaces:

```
d.text().replace(String.fromCharCode(160) /* no breaking space*/,
         " " /* ordinary space */) == "some text"
```

or better yet:

```
d.text().replace(/\s/g /* all kinds of spaces*/,
         " " /* ordinary space */) == "some text"
```

Comment: not really what I wanted to use a fix number instead of key constant, but it´s ok and does its job.

Comment: Rather than use the specific `160` you could make use of `$('#text').text().trim().replace($('<b>&nbsp;</b>').text(), " ")` obviously you'd cache the `$('<b>&nbsp;</b>').text()` part -- this would support whatever different browsers and jQuery decided to do with `&nbsp;` now and in the future. That said, your second example using RegExp is far better.. especially as it supports multiple replacements.

Comment: That regex is NOT all encompassing. I did this:  `var htmlString = $myField.text().replace(/\s/g,"");` in an effort to remove all spaces.  Instead, the zero-width space character 8203 was still there and caused `htmlString.length` to read as 1.  You'll probably need to replace this one, too.

Answer (score 14):

`&nbsp;`  is not the same as the space character (Unicode U+0020).  It's a non-breaking space character, encoded in Unicode as U+00A0.  This is why the first of your tests doesn't match, but the third one does; `\s` matches all white space characters.

Either stick to your regular expression test, or use `\u00a0` or `\xa0` in your equality check:

```
$("#text").text().trim() === "some\xa0text";
$("#text").text().trim() === "some\u00a0text";
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not taking into consideration the `\n` that is invisible.

Get rid of the `\n` and check it with `==`.

Try this:

```
var x = $("#text").html();
x = x.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
x = x.replace(/\s+/g, '');
alert(x);

if (x == 'some&nbsp;text') {
  alert('true');
}
else {
  alert('false');
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @alpham8 : have added a code too. You can shorten it too. let me know if it was helpful or if you have any doubts.
Ideally you can remove both space and \n in one .remove().

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is useless if there is not `^` or `$` in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of similar questions. You could check them out.

[Matching jquery .text() to &nbsp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039182/matching-jquery-text-to-nbsp)
[nonbreaking space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237989/nonbreaking-space)

As mentioned in the previous posts. You could compare with "==" instead of "===" and use '\xa0' for comparing `&nbsp;` which is the actual character for non-breaking space.