# Comparing apparently equal strings JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   <a id="jobDescription" class="is_html" tabindex="-1" href="/es/backoffice/jobs?job_id=1"><p>Este puesto implica una gran capacidad de organización: - Recibir pedidos - Bla bla.... Y muchas cosas m</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>pruebassssssssssssssssss</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>adsfasdfsafad adfasdf asdfas s gfasdpepeluis &nbsp;don chencho&nbsp;</p></a>

   <input type="hidden" value="<p>Este puesto implica una gran capacidad de organización: - Recibir pedidos - Bla bla.... Y muchas cosas m</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>pruebassssssssssssssssss</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>adsfasdfsafad adfasdf asdfas s gfasdpepeluis &nbsp;don chencho&nbsp;</p>">
```

I have got those two HTML tags. I need to compare the values and text they have, but the problem is that whatever I do, I'm getting a false value even though they are actually the same. Here my jQuery code:

```
oldValue = $(elem).find("input[type='hidden']").val();
newValue = $(elem).children()[0].innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ');;
```

As you can see, the hidden element is keeping oldValue, and the a link is keeping newValue. Using Google Chrome's developer tool, I can use the console to print out the values right before comparing them, getting this result:

```
newValue
"<p>Este puesto implica una gran capacidad de organización: - Recibir pedidos - Bla bla.... Y muchas cosas m</p><p> </p><p>pruebassssssssssssssssss</p><p> </p><p>adsfasdfsafad adfasdf asdfas s gfasdpepeluis  don chencho </p>"

oldValue
"<p>Este puesto implica una gran capacidad de organización: - Recibir pedidos - Bla bla.... Y muchas cosas m</p><p> </p><p>pruebassssssssssssssssss</p><p> </p><p>adsfasdfsafad adfasdf asdfas s gfasdpepeluis  don chencho </p>"

newValue == oldValue
false
```

What could possibly be wrong here??

Comment: Can you reproduce it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you haven't replaced the non-breaking spaces in the old value

Comment: Your issue is with spaces, I found a similar answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036576/why-does-the-javascript-string-whitespace-character-nbsp-not-match

Comment: I have tried replacing spaces in oldValue, and still getting the same problem. If I can see in the console that thery are exactly the same, newValue == oldValue should return TRUE right??

Answer (score 0):

I see you have replaced &nbsp in newvalue but not in oldvalue maybe that could mean something...

can you post complete code to make a clearer idea of what are you doing?

EDIT:
If it can help: **[What is the correct way to check for string equality in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/javascript-string-equality-whats-the-correct-way)**

Answer (score 0):

apparently, using `replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ')` is not enough for compare a string in a variable and a string from an element.

following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery), I managed to create a fiddle which resolve your problem:

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62ku37e1/2/)