# Why using ToLocaleString() and replace() doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, date, replace

I faced this issue while working with dates but I don't know why this replace doesn't work, specifically when the string includes "p. m.".

```
(new Date()).toLocaleString("es-CO", {}).replace(". ", "")
```

[image]

Comment: Copy and parte the `. ` from the output of  `(new Date()).toLocaleString("es-CO", {})`, it should work. Maybe it is something with the withspace character.

Comment: Note that the result of *toLocaleString* is not standardised and may vary across implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

radulle's answer is correct, but may need clarification.

The white-space in "p. m." is a special [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) character, which helps to prevent the UI from breaking the "m." into a separate line from the "p.".

You can get this character using `String.fromCharCode(160)`.

```js
let stringToReplace = "." + String.fromCharCode(160);
let result = (new Date()).toLocaleString("es-CO", {}).replace(stringToReplace, "");
console.log(result);
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22036960/120955

Comment: Or `new Date().toLocaleString('es-co').replace(/[ap].*$/,'pm')`

Comment: @RobG: No! That will replace "a. m." with "pm"!

Comment: Oops, messed up the regexp: `new Date().toLocaleString('es-co').replace(/([ap]).*$/,'$1m')`.

Answer (score 1):

It works, problem is your specific space and/or dot character that is produced by "es-CO":

```js
console.log((new Date()).toLocaleString("es-CO", {}).replace(". ", ""))
```