# Insert text using jQuery if non-breaking space is found within an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plugin that is generating some additional markup that needs to be removed. I can detect if the HTML entity `&nbsp;` exists in a specific element, but I cannot seem to change it using html().

Can anyone spot the issue that's preventing the element from being changed?

HTML

```
<div class="quote">
    <blockquote>John Doe wrote:
        <p></p>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Jane Doe wrote: This is awesome!</p>
        </blockquote>
    </blockquote>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
if ($('.quote').find('p:contains("&nbsp;")')) {
  console.log('&nbsp; detected');
  $('.quote').find('p:contains("&nbsp;")').html("inserted text");
}
```

[Here's my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ldrw5d1/)

Comment: You aren't really detecting it. `if ($('.quote').find('p:contains("&nbsp;")'))` will always return true; it will always return an array. You should be checking the length of the array instead: `if ($('.quote').find('p:contains("&nbsp;")').length > 0)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237989/nonbreaking-space  You need the javascript representation of a non-breaking space (`\xA0`), not the html entity.

Comment: **Note to the OP :** The if is totally useless there....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets rid of the `find` and the extra call to `$('.quote')`:

```js
$('.quote p:contains(\xA0)').html('inserted text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote">
    <blockquote>John Doe wrote:
        <p></p>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Jane Doe wrote: This is awesome!</p>
        </blockquote>
    </blockquote>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ha, you're right since I removed the `console.log`.  Edited.

Answer (score 4):

Use `\xA0` for `&nbsp;`:

```
if ($('.quote').find('p:contains("\xA0")').length) {//use length to verify if it exist
  console.log('&nbsp; detected');
  $('.quote').find('p:contains("\xA0")').html("inserted text");
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ldrw5d1/1/)

Answer (score -2):

Your if condition is actually invalid.  A jQuery selector will always return a jQuery object, so the if will always be true whether or not the DOM element is found.  If you want to check for actual results from `.find(...)` always use `.length`.  ie: `if ($('.quote').find('p:contains("&nbsp;")').length)`.

Beyond this, your use of contains is incorrect as contains looks for DOM elements and not content.

To achieve what you're looking for, off the top of my head, you should find all p elements, then iterate over them and manually compare `$p.html()` against `&nbsp;`

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realize you can use :contains like that.  Thanks.