# Assertion always return err (expected 'a' to deeply equal 'a')

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, assert, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm doing a simple test here, but I've seen a lot of ppl stumbled into this problem, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a solution, so, therefore, I'm asking for your opinion.
Now, I have this string object, inside a link:

```
...
<div class="price">12,45&nbsp;€</div>
...
```

I created this small test, to check the string value:

```
import { t, Selector } from 'testcafe';
fixture `OfferPage`.page `https://www.verivox.de/applications/broadband/#/offer?i=eyJmaWx0ZXIiOltudWxsLDE2MDAwLDEsbnVsbCwiMDIyMSIsMSwxLDEsbnVsbCwxLDEsbnVsbCwtMSxudWxsLG51bGwsInByaWNlLWFzYyIsMixudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsNl0sImRpYWxvZyI6W251bGxdLCJvZmZlckNyaXRlcmlhIjpbIjYxMzQ0NyIsIjE4MjkyIixudWxsLCIyNCIsMywyLCI1MDAwMCIsIjEwMDAwIixudWxsLG51bGwsMSxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCwiMiIsMSxudWxsLCIwMjIxIixudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsMSw2LG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsXX0%3D`;
test('1', async () => {
    const string = Selector('div.price');
    await t.expect(string.innerText).eql('12,45 €');
});
```

The error I get in terminal is this one:

```
AssertionError: expected '12,45 €' to deeply equal '12,45 €'
```

I really tried to find out a solution, but either I'm changing the definition from `const` in `let` and trying to apply other methods, all end up in a fail err, with different error messages.
So, how could I sort things out, in the above case?
Thanks!

**EDIT**: Thanks for the hints! I edited the post because I realized I haven't mentioned that I already tried what you suggested ...

```
let price = Selector('div').withAttribute('class', 'price');
const result = price.parent('div.centered-content effective-price-wrapper');
console.log(result);
await t.expect(result.innerText).eql('12,45 €');
```

err:

```
Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.
```

another try:

```
const string = await Selector('div.price')();
let pret = await Selector(string).innerText;
const rgx = /&nbsp;/gi;
await t.expect(pret.replace(rgx, '')).eql('12,45 €'.replace(rgx, ''));
```

err

```
 AssertionError: expected '12,45 €' to deeply equal '12,45 €'
```

I'm running out of ideas here :)

Comment: A non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) is not the same as a "normal" space

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the post, because I also had this case treated, but with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is related to the [nonbreaking space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237989/nonbreaking-space).

The following [eql assertion](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/expect/eql.html) should work properly in your scenario:

```
await t.expect(string.innerText).eql('12,45\xa0€');
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your specific test case is that the `&nbsp;` is not interpreted by Testcafe to be a regular space.

What will work is if you copy the `12,45 €` from the error message you get, paste it in the code as the expected value and that's it.

Comment: 'somehow' because they're not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the post, because I also had this case treated, but with no success.