# HTML <option> using Angular 6+ whitespace issue

Tags: html, css, angular6

We have a list of values being returned from the server. These values contains words like this :

"1           Black"
"1/2         Unavailable"
"3           Sky Blue"

The angular code is as follows:
             
     `<select class="someclass" [(ngModel)]="colorChoice">
        <option *ngFor="let c of colorList" [ngValue]="c">{{c}}</option>
     </select>`

    Since the above started removing all the spaces between the words, except for one space in between.
    Something like "1 Black".
    So I resorted to using '&nbsp' in the code after getting the values from the server.
    
    `let tmp = respColorList.replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;');
    this.colorList.push(tmp);`

    Now this is showing "&nbsp" inside the drop down.
    I have also tried `white-space: pre;` and also `word-spacing: 5px;`

How do I solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the values returned from the server, don't insert the HTML entity `&nbsp;` but (the equivalent) string character code `\xa0` . e.g.   `"3\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Sky Blue"`. (See also [How is a non-breaking space represented in a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237989/how-is-a-non-breaking-space-represented-in-a-javascript-string))

I tested by specifying the following member property in a component:

```
colorList = [
   "1      Black",
   "1/2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Unavailable",
   "3\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Sky Blue" ,
];
```

When you databind this with the HTML template code that you provided, I get a select box with in the 3rd option multiple spaces between the words. See attached image. Verified in Chrome and Firefox.

[image: selectbox with multiple spaces in option 3]

Comment: Sir, The &nbsp; before the {{}} binding, works fine. But within the variable itself, there are the two words which needs to have the spaces in between. If I add "&nbsp;" or "\xa0" it is not getting interpreted, I just see the one space. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I get see multiple spaces with \xa0 (but not &nbsp) . I'll extend my answer to further clarify how I achieved that result.