# How to remove whitespace from a string in Cypress

Tags: javascript, html, ascii, cypress, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to remove a whitespace from a numerical value representing money.

For example, I want `1 000 kr` to be `1000`. This is the same case for when the currency is `10 000`

I'm using this function to remove the `kr` but when I try to add another `.replace` it does not work:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('currency', (selector) => {
      cy.get(selector)
        .children()
        .eq(1)
        .invoke('text') // get text
        .then((text) => +text.replace('kr', '').trim());
    });
```

**How would I add another .replace to remove the extra spacing from the numerical value?** [image]

Comment: What about using regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
function formatString(text) {
    return text.replace('kr', '').replace('\u00A0','').trim();
}

Cypress.Commands.add('currency', (selector) => {
      cy.get(selector)
        .children()
        .eq(1)
        .invoke('text') // get text
        .then(formatString)
    });
```

But you can also use Cypress to achieve this using a regex string (the first example in this [Cypress FAQ](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-get-an-element-s-text-contents) is like yours):

```
Cypress.Commands.add('currency', (selector) => {
      cy.get(selector)
        .should('have.text', '\d+[\u00A0]*')
    });
```

You can test out the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/YC4szy/1. It will match strings with a number, followed by a blank space, and any subsequent characters. You can get fancy with the regex to test what you want.

My last suggestion, if matching regex patterns doesn't help, is that you can wrap your cypress command in a function that takes text content as an argument, which you pass into the `should('have.text', ...)` line.

Comment: Your regex is a bit suspect, only matching the 4 digits not the nbsp.

Comment: You can see here https://regex101.com/r/YC4szy/1 that the nbsp is detected in Javascript environments.If you need the encoding for another language, you can play around with it in that link (by changing `Flavor` on the left) and substituting in the correct nbsp encoded character: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm (see Encodings section).

Comment: The other language needed for your example to work is HTML. Unfortunately, that's not an option on regex101.com.

Answer (score 1):

`&nbsp;` is a non breaking space which isn't the same as a "regular" breaking space:

```js
const read = sel => document.querySelector(sel).textContent;

console.log(read('div') === '1 000 kr'); // false!
```

```html
<div>1&nbsp;000 kr</div>
```

These two whitespace characters actually have different ascii code:

```js
const read = sel => document.querySelector(sel).textContent;
const strencode = str => [...str].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)).join('\t');

console.log(strencode('1 000 kr'));
console.log(strencode(read('div')));
```

```html
<div>1&nbsp;000 kr</div>
```

See how the second characters differ?

You can normalise the strings with [`String#normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize):

```js
const read = sel => document.querySelector(sel).textContent;

console.log(read('div').normalize('NFKC') === '1 000 kr')
```

```html
<div>1&nbsp;000 kr</div>
```

So here's one possible answer to your question:

1. Normalize your string
2. Remove all spaces (ascii 32) characters with `/ /g`
3. Remove `'kr'` at the end

```js
const read = sel => document.querySelector(sel).textContent;
const clean = str => str.normalize('NFKC').replace(/ /g, '').replace(/kr$/, '');

console.log(clean(read('#div1')));
console.log(clean(read('#div2')));
```

```html
<div id="div1">1&nbsp;000 kr</div>
<div id="div2">10&nbsp;000</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see [How is a non-breaking space represented in a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5238020/15239601)

> When doing .text(), all HTML entities are decoded to their character values.
>
> Instead of comparing using the entity, compare using the actual raw character
>
> `if (x == '\xa0') { // Non-breakable space is char 0xa0 (160 dec)`

This would be the expression you are looking for

```js
+text.replace('kr', '')  
  .replace('\xa0', '')
  .trim()
```

Tested with

```html
<div>1&nbsp;100 kr</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the idea from @evolutionxbox, you can use a regex on `element.innerText` to replace non-breaking spaces.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('currency', (selector) => {
  cy.get(selector)   
    .children()
    .eq(1) 
    .then($el => +$el[0].innerText.replace(/\s/g, '').replace('kr', '') )
})
```