# Angular, mat-option, text format with spaces

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-option

I need to display text inside `<mat-option>` with number of spaces between words. E.g. 'word1__word2' must have two spaces in between. I can do this by replacing the space character with `&nbsp;`.  But this doesn't work if I return a string from a method:

.ts:

```
myFunc() {
  return 'This&nbsp;doesn't&nbsp;work!';
}
```

.html:

```
<mat-option>
  {{myFunc()+'This&nbsp;works!'}}
</mat-option>
```

So, the formatting doesn't work if I return the string from a method. How I can force to format it? Else it skips extra spaces.

[innerHtml] doesn't work also, since it hides other staff like checkboxes:

```
<mat-select [multiple]="true">
  <mat-option [innerHtml]="'inner'"></mat-option>
  <mat-option>opt2</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

the first item doesn't have checkbox.

Comment: can you share the code that innerHtml is not working for

Comment: @Mr.Stash added in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `\xA0` in place of `&nbsp;`

```js
myFunc() {
    return "This\xA0doesn't\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0work!";
}
```

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237989/how-is-a-non-breaking-space-represented-in-a-javascript-string#answer-5238020) has some more information