# how to escape &nbsp in a string in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am doing some automation testing and I am looking for an element that contains a specific text by passing in its param value. Annoyingly, I am looking for 'Safe 1' but the text in the html shows it as '`Safe&nbsp;1'`. So for testing purposes I want to include `'Safe&nbsp;1'` as a param to see if it finds it but not sure how to add it.

I tried:

```
'Safe${&nbsp;}1'
'Safe\&nbsp;\1'
'Safe\\&nbsp;\\1'
'Safe '+ &nbsp; + '1'
```

I am using typescript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is a non-breaking space represented in a JavaScript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237989/how-is-a-non-breaking-space-represented-in-a-javascript-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably using the unicode version of it may work.

```
const nbsp = '\u00A0'
console.log(`save${nbsp};1`)
```

[reference](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0)